# react parent components passing child a prop with different name

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Sorry for the terrible question name, I'm wondering if there is a standard way of passing a different value for the same prop from different parents and if there's something wrong with the way I am spreading my props.

Parent 1:

```
<ChildComponent
prop1={prop1}
prop2={prop2}
paymentProcessingDate={Date.now()}
...passThroughProps
>
```

Parent 2 which has a prop carServiceDate

```
<ChildComponent
prop1={prop1}
prop2={prop2}
paymentProcessingDate={carServiceAppointment.date}
...passThroughProps
>
```

Both Parent1 and Parent2 make use of ChildComponent but need to pass in a different value for paymentProcessingDate. I'm receiving an error that the spread of passThroughProps will always overwrite paymentProcessingDate but the first time paymentProcessingDate is used or defined is in the call to ChildComponent. Any help or suggestions is really appreciated!!

Comment: `I'm receiving an error that the spread of passThroughProps will always overwrite paymentProcessingDate` Then change the order around: spread first, then do the paymentProcessingDate prop. The lines that come last will overwrite the lines that come first.

Comment: What does your `passThroughProps` look like? it sounds like it is an object with a key named `paymentProcessingDate` that is overwriting the original value

Answer (score 0):

The `...passThroughProps` must contain a value for `paymentProcessingDate` so TypeScript is complaining that your spread prop will overwrite whatever you explicitly set.

Try moving the spread to the top and see if that fixes it:

```
<ChildComponent
...passThroughProps
prop1={prop1}
prop2={prop2}
paymentProcessingDate={carServiceAppointment.date}
>
```

Or if possible, remove `paymentProcessingDate` from `passThroughProps`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Moving passThroughProps to the top did fix the problem! Any idea how paymentProcessingDate would have been in passThroughProps? I define it in the call to ChildComponent

Comment: Not sure based on the code you have shown.  I'd have to see how you're defining `passThroughProps` explicitly.

Comment: Also if the answer helped, please mark as accepted.  Thanks!